# How to make the equalizer start button work correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I have developed an application that simulates the work of an equalizer in terms of showing changes in audio frequencies.

[image]

*Animation problems occur when you press the "Start" button again.*
The animation results are reset and start over from the beginning.
Of course, this can be avoided by putting protection against repeated clicks while the animation is active
`restart =" whenNotactive "`

But this is an incomplete solution to the problem.

I tried to hang the `begin ="start.click"` event on the "Start" button and
on the "Pause" button  `end ="pause.click"`

*my code is below:*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 150" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

 <defs>  
     <!-- Mask for forming the display of a part of the active line (with stroke = "white") -->
   <mask id="msk">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" /> 
     <rect x="15" y="0" width="60" height="160" fill="white" stroke="white" /> 
</mask> 
 </defs>  
       <!-- Black background -->
      <rect width="22%" height="100%" fill="black" /> 
   <!-- Colored line markers to show equalizer frequency levels  -->
 <polyline  points="10,0 10,139" stroke="#4C4C50" />     
     <polyline  points="80,0 80,139" stroke="#4C4C50" />       
  <polyline id="grey" points="20,0 20,139" stroke="#2A2A2C" /> 
    <use xlink:href="#grey" x="10" />
     <use xlink:href="#grey" x="20" />
      <use xlink:href="#grey" x="30" />
        <use xlink:href="#grey" x="40" />
          <use xlink:href="#grey" x="50" />
   <polyline points="15,2 74,2" stroke-width="2" stroke="#2A2A2C" />          
    <polyline points="15,19 74,19" stroke="red" />    
     <polyline points="15,44 74,44" stroke="green" />     
      <polyline points="15,69 74,69" stroke="dodgerblue" />
       <polyline points="15,94 74,94" stroke="green" /> 
        <polyline points="15,119 74,119" stroke="gold" /> 
         <polyline points="15,139 74,139" stroke-width="2" stroke="#2A2A2C" />
       <!-- Frequency labeling text -->
    <text x="12" y="15" font-size="6px" fill="yellow">16K</text>    
     <text x="12" y="40" font-size="6px" fill="yellow">6K</text>    
      <text x="12" y="67" font-size="6px" fill="yellow">1K</text>  
        <text x="12" y="92" font-size="6px" fill="yellow">310</text> 
          <text x="12" y="117" font-size="6px" fill="yellow">170</text> 
           <!-- Button to start animation -->
        <g id="start" transform="translate(60,0)" cursor="pointer">
          <text x="2" y="147" font-size="8px" fill="yellow">Start</text> 
          <circle cx="23" cy="145" r="3" fill="greenyellow" />
        </g>   
            <g id="pause" transform="translate(10,0)" cursor="pointer">
          <text x="2" y="147" font-size="8px" fill="yellow">Pause</text> 
          <circle cx="25" cy="145" r="3" fill="red" />
        </g>
        <!-- Trajectory of line movement showing audio frequency -->
 <g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" mask="url(#msk)"> 
 <path id="trace" transform="translate(348, 0)"  
     fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="1.5" d="m-246 68.4c0 0 32.6 0 47.8 0 9.2 0 12.9-30.8 16.4-22.3 4.8 11.5 6 43.3 6 43.3l7.9-26.6 5 35.9 8.9-63.5 3.7 80.9 5.2-93.7 4.8 108.2 6.6-125.2 2.6 84 4.8-31.8 5 23.3 2-18.1 5.5 12.1 4-12.1 2.8 26.6 3.3-31.8 3.6 43.1 5.5-55.5 2.2 70.8 6.5-80.9 3.2 95.4 6-112.9 2.7 125.7 7-131.5 2.6 131.5 5.9-131.6 5.1 118.8 8.7-108.2 5 93.7 10.1-87.9 3.4 76.1 11.8-69.2 3.1 54.3L-5.6 44.1 0 74.9 4 57.7 8.6 74.9 13.7 51l4.3 23.9 4.7-35.2 8.2 53.5 6.3-58.1 5.7 54.3 9-54.3 5.9 54.3 6.2-54.3 8.6 54.3 5.9-67.1 8.6 81.9 7.3-89.6 5.5 95.4 6.6-100.6 6.2 115.5 6.9-115.1 4.1 128.6 7.3-127.6 2.8 132.4 8.3-133.8 4.1 121 4.8-108.2 4.8 101.7 4.8-96.5 5.9 94.4 2.8-86.8 4.8 73 4.1-62.9 6.9 59.1 2.8-50.1 4.8 42.2 2.4-37.7 4.1 27 2.1-22.8 2.4 20.4 1.7-24.9 2.4 22.5 2.4-21.4 1.7 15.6 3.1-12.1 2.8 67.8 3.8-95.4 2.8 89.9 9.7-102.7 4.1 102 6.2-102 4.1 93.7 4.8-80.9 4.8 69.2 4.5-61.2 3.8 53.9 4.1-41.1 3.8 27.7 3.1-20.7 4.1 12.1 2.8-12.1 3.5 12.1 2.4-12.1 4.5 26.6 2.4-42.1 6.6 57 4.8-69.2 7.3 80.9 5.5-93.7 10.4 108.2 2.1-114.5 8 127.2 2.8-130.7 8 122.4 4.8-124.5 8 114.5 3.5-98.2 7.3 83 5.5-79.5 4.8 68.8 6.9-53.1V80.8l4.5-18 5.2 17.2 3-22.4 3.4 27 5.1-27 2.4 46.7 7.5-69.2 2.9 76.5c0 0 2.8-66.4 7.3-84.8 5.3-21.4 6.6 103.7 6.6 103.7l7-116.8 10 129.6 3.2-112.6 8.8 112.6 2.8-94.6 8 48.3 1.9-44 2.9 29.7 3.6-25 4.7 21.5 3.6-16.3 3.1 14.8 6.5-64.2 5.2 102.7 7.5-101.1 5.6 101.1 6.2-97.9 5.9 92.8 5.5-82.9 5.2 80.7 4.3-70.7 2.7 66.3 6-54.4 4.1 46 6.2-83.1 6.9 117.8 4.6-116.1 10 101.6 0.4-78.3 8 60.5c0 0 3.1-34.2 6.8-51 2.7-12.1 2 16.9 8.2 21.1 4.2 2.9 15.4 0.1 15.4 0.1h19.7" > 
         <!-- Equalizer line animation -->
       <animateTransform
        id="at1"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="start.click"
        end="pause.click"
        dur="22s"
        values="250 0;-650 0"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="3" />
 </path> 
  </g>   
</svg>
```

But this is not what you need. The animation starts again from the beginning when you press the `Start` button.
I need that when the `Pause` button is pressed, the animation stops, and when the `Start` button is pressed again, it starts from the point of stopping.

**Question:**

How to get the animation to start from where the previous animation stopped when you press the `Start` button again?

Apparently purely in SVG, this task is impossible. Therefore CSS and JS solutions will be helpful.

Comment: What about `SVGRoot.pauseAnimations();`?? - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694045/can-svg-animations-be-suspended-without-loosing-accumulative-information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option JS Solution

Javascript methods are used:

SVGRoot.animationsPaused()
SVGRoot.unpauseAnimations()

```js
function Init(evt)
  {  
     SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
     SVGRoot = SVGDocument.getElementById('SVGRoot');

     pauseButton = SVGDocument.getElementById('pause1');
     playButton = SVGDocument.getElementById('start1');
     equalizer = SVGDocument.getElementById('equalizer');
  };

  function Pause()
  {  
     SVGRoot.pauseAnimations();
  };

  function Start()
  {
     if(SVGRoot.animationsPaused()){
        SVGRoot.unpauseAnimations();
     }
     else{
         equalizer.beginElement();
         
     }
  };
```

```css
text.yellow {
fill:yellow;
font-size:6px;
}
g#gr1 {
stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-linejoin:round;
 mask:url(#msk);
 transform:translate(348, 0);  
}
#trace{
fill:none;
stroke:cyan;
stroke-width:1.5;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 150" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" 
       onload='Init(evt)' id = "SVGRoot" >  

 <defs>  
     <!-- Mask for forming the display of a part of the active line (with stroke = "white") -->
   <mask id="msk">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" /> 
     <rect x="15" y="0" width="60" height="160" fill="white" stroke="white" /> 
</mask> 
 </defs>  
       <!-- Black background -->
      <rect width="22%" height="100%" fill="black" /> 
   <!-- Colored line markers to show equalizer frequency levels  -->
 <polyline  points="10,0 10,139" stroke="#4C4C50" />     
     <polyline  points="80,0 80,139" stroke="#4C4C50" />       
  <polyline id="grey" points="20,0 20,139" stroke="#2A2A2C" /> 
    <use xlink:href="#grey" x="10" />
     <use xlink:href="#grey" x="20" />
      <use xlink:href="#grey" x="30" />
        <use xlink:href="#grey" x="40" />
          <use xlink:href="#grey" x="50" />
   <polyline points="15,2 74,2" stroke-width="2" stroke="#2A2A2C" />          
    <polyline points="15,19 74,19" stroke="red" />    
     <polyline points="15,44 74,44" stroke="green" />     
      <polyline points="15,69 74,69" stroke="dodgerblue" />
       <polyline points="15,94 74,94" stroke="green" /> 
        <polyline points="15,119 74,119" stroke="gold" /> 
         <polyline points="15,139 74,139" stroke-width="2" stroke="#2A2A2C" />
       <!-- Frequency labeling text -->
    
    <text class="yellow" x="12" y="15"  >16K</text>     
     <text class="yellow" x="12" y="40" >6K</text>  
      <text class="yellow" x="12" y="67"  >1K</text>  
        <text class="yellow" x="12" y="92"  >310</text> 
          <text class="yellow" x="12" y="117"  >170</text> 
           <!-- Button to start animation -->
        <g id="start1" transform="translate(60,0)" cursor="pointer" onclick='Start()'>
          <text x="2" y="147" font-size="8px" fill="yellow">Start</text> 
          <circle cx="23" cy="145" r="3" fill="greenyellow" />
        </g>   
            <g id="pause1" transform="translate(10,0)" cursor="pointer" onclick='Pause()'>
          <text x="2" y="147" font-size="8px" fill="yellow">Pause</text> 
          <circle cx="25" cy="145" r="3" fill="red" />
        </g>
        <!-- Trajectory of line movement showing audio frequency -->
 <g id="gr1"> 
 <path id="trace" transform="translate(348, 0)"  
     fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="1.5" d="m-246 68.4c0 0 32.6 0 47.8 0 9.2 0 12.9-30.8 16.4-22.3 4.8 11.5 6 43.3 6 43.3l7.9-26.6 5 35.9 8.9-63.5 3.7 80.9 5.2-93.7 4.8 108.2 6.6-125.2 2.6 84 4.8-31.8 5 23.3 2-18.1 5.5 12.1 4-12.1 2.8 26.6 3.3-31.8 3.6 43.1 5.5-55.5 2.2 70.8 6.5-80.9 3.2 95.4 6-112.9 2.7 125.7 7-131.5 2.6 131.5 5.9-131.6 5.1 118.8 8.7-108.2 5 93.7 10.1-87.9 3.4 76.1 11.8-69.2 3.1 54.3L-5.6 44.1 0 74.9 4 57.7 8.6 74.9 13.7 51l4.3 23.9 4.7-35.2 8.2 53.5 6.3-58.1 5.7 54.3 9-54.3 5.9 54.3 6.2-54.3 8.6 54.3 5.9-67.1 8.6 81.9 7.3-89.6 5.5 95.4 6.6-100.6 6.2 115.5 6.9-115.1 4.1 128.6 7.3-127.6 2.8 132.4 8.3-133.8 4.1 121 4.8-108.2 4.8 101.7 4.8-96.5 5.9 94.4 2.8-86.8 4.8 73 4.1-62.9 6.9 59.1 2.8-50.1 4.8 42.2 2.4-37.7 4.1 27 2.1-22.8 2.4 20.4 1.7-24.9 2.4 22.5 2.4-21.4 1.7 15.6 3.1-12.1 2.8 67.8 3.8-95.4 2.8 89.9 9.7-102.7 4.1 102 6.2-102 4.1 93.7 4.8-80.9 4.8 69.2 4.5-61.2 3.8 53.9 4.1-41.1 3.8 27.7 3.1-20.7 4.1 12.1 2.8-12.1 3.5 12.1 2.4-12.1 4.5 26.6 2.4-42.1 6.6 57 4.8-69.2 7.3 80.9 5.5-93.7 10.4 108.2 2.1-114.5 8 127.2 2.8-130.7 8 122.4 4.8-124.5 8 114.5 3.5-98.2 7.3 83 5.5-79.5 4.8 68.8 6.9-53.1V80.8l4.5-18 5.2 17.2 3-22.4 3.4 27 5.1-27 2.4 46.7 7.5-69.2 2.9 76.5c0 0 2.8-66.4 7.3-84.8 5.3-21.4 6.6 103.7 6.6 103.7l7-116.8 10 129.6 3.2-112.6 8.8 112.6 2.8-94.6 8 48.3 1.9-44 2.9 29.7 3.6-25 4.7 21.5 3.6-16.3 3.1 14.8 6.5-64.2 5.2 102.7 7.5-101.1 5.6 101.1 6.2-97.9 5.9 92.8 5.5-82.9 5.2 80.7 4.3-70.7 2.7 66.3 6-54.4 4.1 46 6.2-83.1 6.9 117.8 4.6-116.1 10 101.6 0.4-78.3 8 60.5c0 0 3.1-34.2 6.8-51 2.7-12.1 2 16.9 8.2 21.1 4.2 2.9 15.4 0.1 15.4 0.1h19.7" > 
         <!-- Equalizer line animation -->
       <animateTransform
        id="equalizer"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        dur="22s"
        values="250 0;-650 0"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        restart="whenNotActive"
        />
 </path> 
  </g>   
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/Bazgrzd)